# css woes - allowing content to stay horizontal within a scrollable container

Tags: css

Trying to learn css and hit a wall - per this simple jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/t648wvk2/ I am trying to achieve an outcome where I have a collection of divs laid out horizontally within a fixed width container div that allows user to scroll sideways to view collection elements.  Cant get my head around whats wrong - any help most appreciated!

```
<div class="container">
<div class="list">list1</div>
<div class="list">list2</div>
<div class="list">list3</div>
<div class="list">list4</div>
<div class="list">list5</div>
<div class="list">list6</div>
<div class="list">list7</div>
<div class="list">list8</div>
<div class="list">list9</div>
<div class="list">list10</div>
<div class="list">list11</div>
<div class="list">list12</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following css:

```
.list {
    border:1px solid;
    height: 3em;
    width: 100px;
    margin-left:10px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.container {
    width: 50%;
    overflow:scroll;
    float:left;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t648wvk2/2/) here.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt help! Most appreciated.